# How to write Mockito tests for rest exchange

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

> > This is the way I am making a HttP Call to send a message . Was wondering the best way to Unit Test

```
public void httCall(String msgToSend) {

    try {
        ResponseEntity <String> response = rest.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST,new HttpEntity<>(msgToSend), String.class);
        LOG.info("sent to {}  response {} {}",msgToSend,response.getStatusCode(), response.getBody());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
              LOG.error("error calling  ", e);
                    throw e;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother unit testing a method that has no real logic.  Other than the logging, all you're doing is passing the call through to another method in another class.  Unit test that other method instead.

Comment: This is way too broad. And sorry, very poor quality. You should at least give some example of what you intend to test, instead of simply dropping such an unclear question.

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit.  You should not change the question materially once people start answering.  It invalidates their hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, you need to verify that `rest.exchange` is called with the correct parameters. You'll have to mock the `RestTemplate`, inject it, and verify that the method is called as expected. In this case, I think you'll actually have to capture the arguments because `msgToSend` gets wrapped in a new `HttpEntity`. It gets a little tricky because we also have to mock the returned `ResponseEntity` so that interactions with it don't throw `NullPointerException`.

```
@Test
public void testMessageSent(){
   RestTemplate template = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
   YourClass toTest = new YourClass(template);
   ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK, "Hello World");
   Mockito.when(template.exchange(Mockito.anyString(),  Mockito.any(),  Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),  Mockito.<Class<?>> any())).thenReturn(response);

yourClass.httCall("Hello World");

ArgumentCaptor<String> urlCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<HttpMethod> methodCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpMethod.class);
ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> entityCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Class> classCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Class.class);

Mockito.verify(template.exchange(urlCaptor, methodCaptor, entityCaptor, classCaptor);

Assert.assertEquals("expectedUrl", urlCaptor.getValue());
Assert.assertEquals(HttpMethod.POST, methodCaptor.getValue());
Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", entityCaptor.getValue().getBody());
Assert.assertEquals(String.class, classCaptor.getValue());
```

Note that you may have to use `RestOperations` interface instead of `RestTemplate` class. I vaguely remember that Mockito couldn't mock `RestTemplate` but I mostly use Spock now.

That's some advanced Mockito for a very simple method, but I've found tricky bugs in methods more trivial than this.

Comment: This helps understand better , But I do do get an Error saying "Cannot resolve method response "   here:     Mockito.<Class<?>> any())).thenReturn(response);